# My App cannot send request to get Location

Tags: android, google-api, geolocation, gps, location

I am writhing now simple weather program. I use weather Api and must send location of phone to get weather data. As you understand I don't need precise location, so no need for GPS, noneed for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. What I need is - to get my location from **NETWORK_PROVIDER**. But here starts the problem.

At first I tried to use **LocationManager** and **LocationListener**. I enabled my WiFi and location in phone settings. Important thing that I want my application work indoor, so that no need for walking to change coordinates and **LocationManager** will respond. At first I check last known location.

```
    Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LOCATION_PROVIDER);
```

Actually, often it does not work. So I get null as location. Especiall when you turn off **location in smartphone settings** and after a few minutes turn it on.

OKAY, you don't have lastKnownLocation, then lets get it us. I use **requestLocationUpdates()** to get current location:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000,  0, mLocationListener);
```

Now the magic begins... Sometime (one time in several hours OR several times in a minute) the **requestLocationUpdates()** works. But most of time it does not react. After many searches in internet I found Google Api, in particular **FusedLocationProviderClient** class. But again same story happens. But now I could understand that **requestLocationUpdates()** is not called.

`mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);`

I decided to put a button to see does it sends any **requestLocationUpdates**, but when I click button I have error.

```
587-673/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
```

To Summarize, my app simply dont send **requestLocationUpdates**. And I need just approximate location of my device to get city name, so no need for GPS. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to get Current or Last Known Location if current location is currently not available.

**initialize activity in your Manifest.xml**
inside **application tag**

```
    <activity android:name=".LocationFinder"></activity>
```

**start this activity by calling**

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationFinder.class));
finish();
```

Now, you can get Location in any other activity by just calling -> **LocationFinder.finalAddress**

**Location and Internet permissions required**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**LocationFinder.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public class LocationFinder extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    public static String finalAddress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getLoc();
    }

    public  void getLoc() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location == null) {
            location = getLastKnownLocation();
        }

        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not available...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null
                    || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        if (bestLocation == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //You had this as int. It is advised to have Lat/Loing as double.
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            int maxLines = address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex()+1;
            for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++) {
                String addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                builder.append(addressStr);
                builder.append(" ");
            }
            finalAddress = builder.toString(); //This is the complete address.
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            // Handle IOException
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

After getting complete address you can use split method to get country name etc

Comment: I have error Unable to find explicit activity class {com.londonappbrewery.climapm/com.londonappbrewery.climapm.LocationFinder}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?. What you suggest to do?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
        at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:2168)
        at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1258)
        at com.londonappbrewery.climapm.LocationFinder.getLoc(LocationFinder.java:41)
        at com.londonappbrewery.climapm.LocationFinder.onCreate(LocationFinder.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7016)

Comment: It was showing error before, now I turned on location for this app in settings. But apps runs and shows white screen. I inserted startActivity() in onResume(). Probably it enters to infinite loop

Comment: I  moved it from onResume() function, now in log I can see that it got updateof location, but screen remains white. What to do? We are close to get result)

Comment: @ElnurAliyev sorry for late response. have you called **finish()** after calling location activity?